# Popup window webbrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am using a webbrowser control to get some information from a website. It has a detail link, which when clicked, opens a popup window and shows the details in the webbrowser.

How can I do these if click the link in webbrowser control (by program) open another window and showing execution error.

But in explorer it is working. And I noticed that detail link works only if I open the main page in Internet Explorer, otherwise if I call the detail URL directly from Internet Explorer, it also gives me the same error.

Comment: You mean the link is not working in webbrowser control but is working in IE?

Comment: yes it not working in webbrowser control

Comment: Umm, can someone make this for windows 8?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I recently ran across a very similar situation.  In my case, the popup browser didn't share the session of the embedded browser.  What I had to do was capture the NewWindow event and cancel it, then send the intended URL to the embedded browser.  I needed to use the ActiveX browser instance because it gives you the URL that was attempting to launch.  Here is my code:

You will need to add the Microsoft Internet Controls COM reference to your project for this to work.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // this assumes that you've added an instance of WebBrowser and named it webBrowser to your form
        SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1 axBrowser = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1)webBrowser.ActiveXInstance;

        // listen for new windows
        axBrowser.NewWindow += axBrowser_NewWindow;
    }

    void axBrowser_NewWindow(string URL, int Flags, string TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, string Headers, ref bool Processed)
    {
        // cancel the PopUp event
        Processed = true;

        // send the popup URL to the WebBrowser control
        webBrowser.Navigate(URL);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you do if you want to close the popup and return to where you were though? This seems like a very easy approach to implement, but getting back to the main screen is a little more work I think..

Comment: You would have to implement a custom solution for that.  Something as simple as storing the browser history yourself and navigating backwards would work, be it not as elegant as other solutions could be.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. What I'll be doing is capture the NewWindow and spin up a new WebBrowser control and window to force it into.

Comment: I've used this before and it worked.  However, I'm trying to do it now for a different website and it's not working.  The event just doesn't fire, even though the "axBrowser" object is valid.  Any idea why that might happen?

Comment: But what if I want the popup but want it to share the session?.This is what the real IE does).

Answer (score 1):

this is dynamic version. it doesnt require statically bind com interop which is always problem in future versions of windows.

```
    public partial class Form10 : Form
{
    public Form10()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
        dynamic ax = this.webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance;
        ax.NewWindow += new NewWindowDelegate(this.OnNewWindow);
        this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com");
    }
    private delegate void NewWindowDelegate(string URL, int Flags, string TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, string Headers, ref bool Processed);
    private void OnNewWindow(string URL, int Flags, string TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, string Headers, ref bool Processed)
    {
        Processed = true;
        //your own logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refine to Middas answer...

- add COM reference Microsoft Internet Controls.
- use Middas Code.
- in form_Load define your Uri and all your pop up will directly change your winform WebBrowser.