# .NET WebBrowser control popup won't open in control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

Ok so the site that I am accessing through my webbrowser control wants to open a PopUp window when I click on a link to open their web application.

If I allow it to PopUp through the control it of course just opens a new IE window and doesn't retain session. I have tried manually navigating to the link and also attempting to handle it with the Microsoft Internet Controls NewWindow event and redirecting as suggested in this post: 
[Popup window webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239946/popup-window-webbrowser-control/15240727)

If I attempt to pass in TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers, etc - I get the following error: 
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

No matter how I open the window however, the web application pop up's the message - "The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the window."  Even if I click No on this pop up, the site still closes.

Any ideas on how I could possibly disable the javascript that causes the window to close or alternative methods on handling the pop up window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following interface:

```cs
SHDocVw.WebBrowser
```

You are able to attach to an event called:

```cs
NewWindow2
```

When you form loads just declare the following variable and add the event:

make sure you have form with a browser control on it.

you should be able to find the reference to the interface in the following assembly: Interop.SHDocVw

```cs
SHDocVw.WebBrowser nativeBrowser = webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance;
nativeBrowser.NewWindow2 += (ref object ppDisp, ref bool Cancel) => 
{ 
    var frm = new frmWithBrowser();
    frm.Show(this);
    ppDisp = frm.webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance;
}
```